# In ReactJS application Using Format.js library how can I convert date to date and time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formatjs

I am new to React & Format.js. I need to do a small task which I am not able to do so. Please help me to convert date to date and time in my react js app format.js they used as a component it is written like this.

I also followed [this article](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/components/#formatteddate) but not able to understand

```
 <FormattedDate value={new Date(data.situDate)} year="numeric" month="short" day="2-digit" />
```

and inside the data it is like this response

```
"situDate":"2021-12-07T15:56:47.661+00:00"
```

**I needed to show like in this format**

```
27 oct. 2020 16:24:22
```

Comment: Use both Date and Time component side by side?
```<FormattedDate value={new Date(data.situDate)} year="numeric" month="short" day="2-digit" />
<FormattedTime value={new Date(data.situDate)} />
```

Now pass param on FormattedTime as you wish.

Comment: How to do in 24 Hour Format